# Running all Python scripts with the same name across many directories

Tags: python, tensorflow, directory, subdirectory

I have a file structure that looks something like this:

**Master:**

- First

  - train.py
  - other1.py
- Second

  - train.py
  - other2.py
- Third

  - train.py
  - other3.py

I want to be able to have one Python script that lives in the `Master` directory that will do the following when executed:

- Loop through all the subdirectories (and their subdirectories if they exist)
- Run every Python script named `train.py` in each of them, in whatever order necessary

I know how to execute a given python script from another file (given its name), but I want to create a script that will execute whatever `train.py` scripts it encounters. Because the `train.py` scripts are subject to being moved around and being duplicated/deleted, I want to create an adaptable script that will run all those that it finds.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far? The `os` module may be of interest to you and specifically [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: I've used os.walk a few times before, but how would you execute the script file when you come across it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to recursively collect all `train.py` scripts and then run them in parallel using `ProcessPoolExecutor` and the `subprocess` module.

```
import os
import subprocess

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def list_python_scripts(root):
    """Finds all 'train.py' scripts in the given directory recursively."""
    scripts = []
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(root):
        scripts.extend([
            os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in filenames
            if filename == 'train.py'
        ])
    return scripts


def main():
    # Make sure to change the argument here to the directory you want to scan.
    scripts = list_python_scripts('master')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(scripts)) as pool:
        # Run each script in parallel and accumulate CompletedProcess results.
        results = pool.map(subprocess.run,
                           [['python', script] for script in scripts])

    for result in results:
        print(result.returncode, result.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using ?

If Ubuntu/CentOS try this combination:

import os

//put this in master and this lists every file in master + subdirectories and then after the pipe greps train.py

**train_scripts = os.system("find . -type d | grep train.py  ")**

//next execute them

python train_scripts

Comment: `ls -p .` only lists the current directory.

Comment: I'm on macOS. I tried this and it didn't work. No errors or anything, it just doesn't run any of the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you could try running them from a PowerShell script. You can run two python scripts at once with just this:

python Test1.py
python Folder/Test1.py

And then add a loop and or a function that goes searching for the files. Because it's Windows Powershell, you have a lot of power when it comes to the filesystem and controlling Windows in general.